# Creating symbolic links or copying files using arrays in Powershell 7

Tags: arrays, powershell, symlink

There is a repository dir `$RepositoryDIR` that contains many files in different subdirectories.

I want to create symbolic links only to files with exact filenames I specify in an array`$FileNames2Link`. Links have to be created in few directories specified in `$DestinationDirs` array. In other words, all specified directories have to contain the same links to the same files.

I can't get this script to work with arrays, although it does work when I specify directories and filenames separately.

```
$RepositoryDIR = 'C:\REPOSITORY'
$DestinationDirs = @("C:\DEST1","C:\DEST2","C:\DEST3")
$FileNames2Link = @('File1.txt','File2022.png','File108.jpg')

(Get-ChildItem $RepositoryDIR -Recurse -Include $FileNames2Link) | ForEach-Object {
    New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path $DestinationDirs'\'$FileNames2Link -Target $_
}
```

How to get this script to work with arrays?

Answer (score 1):

There's just not a powershell expression that does that (string multiply?).  This code would combine all the files and directories.  -pv is also -pipevariable.  @() isn't needed to make arrays.  % is also foreach-object.  Explicitly putting in write-output is needed for -pv.

```
$DestinationDirs = 'C:\DEST1\','C:\DEST2\','C:\DEST3\' # ending slash added
$FileNames2Link = 'File1.txt','File2022.png','File108.jpg'


$DestinationDirs * $FileNames2Link

Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type 
  "System.UInt32".
At line:1 char:1
+ $DestinationDirs * $FileNames2Link
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConvertToFinalInvalidCastException


# op_Multiply() for [string]?
function multiplyString {
  param($string1s, $string2s)
  write-output $string1s -pv string1 |
    % { $string2s | % { $string2 = $_; $string1 + $string2 } } 
}

$paths = multiplystring $DestinationDirs $FileNames2Link
$paths

C:\DEST1\File1.txt
C:\DEST1\File2022.png
C:\DEST1\File108.jpg
C:\DEST2\File1.txt
C:\DEST2\File2022.png
C:\DEST2\File108.jpg
C:\DEST3\File1.txt
C:\DEST3\File2022.png
C:\DEST3\File108.jpg
```

Comment: Oh, thank you. I am still new to Powershell, but I am trying to exercise it as many times I can. I can see this code is going to work. And you are right about my original script, it was indeed combining all the filenames into one phrase.